# Jquery Show/Hide Function not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been banging my head again and again for one simple problem which i just can't understand. I have bootstrap drop-down which is currently hidden when the page loads. I have linked the drop-down with text box. Drop-down opens on keyup function in text box. I have no issues with opening/Closing of the drop-down but the problem is the links in the drop-down aren't working for some reason i don't understand. I tried the same drop-down with normal button and it works fine. Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.mymenu{
background-color:#efefef;
height:40px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
 margin-top:-7px;

}
.mymenu li{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
color:#757575;
font-family:lato;

}

#search{
width:400px;
height:26px;    
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
height: 5px;
min-width:300px;
}


a:{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}


</style>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mymenu">
<li> Home </li>
<li class="dropdown lgmen">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Top Sellers </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li> 
      </ul>
      </li>
<li class="dropdown lgmen">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword..." autocomplete="off">

<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mydrp" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-top:-10px;">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li> 
            </ul>


 </li>


</div>

<script>

$("#search").keyup(function (event) {
   //preventing default behaviour of bootstrap
    event.stopPropagation();

    $("#mydrp").dropdown().show("slow");
    var ab=$("#search").val();
    if(ab == ""){
    $("#mydrp").dropdown().hide("slow");
    }
});




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @francisco paste code

Comment: Hi Pranjal, Hudhaifa, I am new here on stackoverflow and didnt know how to paste code. i just edited now my post with code. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks to all who took time to answer my question. i found the bug in my code.. The problem was on the line when i make call to show/hide. $("#mydrp").dropdown.show() . The answer is i have to remove the .dropdown.. It should be like >> $("#mydrp").show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong

```
$("#mydrp").dropdown.show();
```

Right

```
$("#mydrp").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with the code - you are not declaring the `<html>` - and you are not wrapping the function in  document ready.And you are not closing off your nest ul li's correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    $("#mydrp").show("slow");
    var ab=$("#search").val();
    if(ab == ""){
    $("#mydrp").hide("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.mymenu{
background-color:#efefef;
height:40px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
 margin-top:-7px;

}
.mymenu li{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
color:#757575;
font-family:lato;
}

#search{
width:400px;
height:26px;    
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
height: 5px;
min-width:300px;
}


a:{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mymenu">
    <ul>
      <li> Home </li>
      <li class="dropdown lgmen">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Top Sellers </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a> href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown lgmen">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Keyword..." autocomplete="off"/>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mydrp" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-top:-10px;">
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Gavgrif, Thanks for the help. i tried the way you told but didn't solve my problem. But i did find the bug in code.